# Find duplicate of secondary key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, duplicates, temp-tables

I am fairly new to Postgresql

I am trying to find number of duplicates of my secondary key whilst still showing the entire table

My table 1 is as

```
|studentid|name|major|countryid|
|:-------:|:--:|:----:|:-------------:|
|001|John|finance|1A|
|002|Luc|Marketing|1B|
|003|Thomas|Sales|1A|
```

And my table 2 is

```
|countryid|country|
|:-------:|:-----:|
|1A|Australia|
|1B|Spain|
```

So each table has of course many rows

The outcome I want is

```
|studentid|name|major|country|numberofstudentsfromthiscountry|
|:-------:|:--:|:---:|:-----:|:-----------------------------:|
|001|John|finance|Australia|2|
|002|Luc|Marketing|Spain|1|
|003|Thomas|Sales|Australia|2|
```

Is that something that someone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you explain what output you are expecting and what you have tried till now

Comment: How are the tables related, there doesnt seem a relation between them via some column.

Comment: Oh student table has foreign key of country id

Comment: This is a simple JOIN of these table on conutry_id. You just need to decide what to do if there is no match. An inner join would completely skip them while an outer would retain one or the other. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-join.html). Look at the *alternate syntax* as the Postgres is extremely poor on this using a syntax obsolete since 1992. Google "ANSI/ISO Join Syntax"